# WHY should I tag questions with nltk, what is the benefit?

Tags: python, nltk

I just recently started using NLTK; I found the tagging feature and I have looked online and found no answers for this. Why should I tag a string? What is the benefit? What does tagging even do?

Comment: you mean NLTK POS tags?

Comment: Your title reads like tagging here on StackOverflow. Your body does not. Please clarify.

Comment: I do mean the NLTK tagging feature.

Answer (score 0):

NLTK itself means 'The Natural Language Toolkit'. So, in order to process a natural language, the most important thing is lexical categories like nouns, adjectives,adverbs etc.

What NLTK called as "tagging" is to tag the words in text in the same way.

This makes it easy to process the language. This is the whole idea behind the field of Natural Language Processing. 
See [this article](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html).

Answer (score 0):

basically tagging a "string" or a value is an important thing in natural language programming, tagging is specifying what type of object is. E.G you want to analyze a comment on an article whether it is a positive or a negative comment. you'll need a dataset for classification. E.G

sample dataset

`----------
string |     tag
kill         negative
beautiful    positive
hate         negative
pretty       positive`

this dataset is the one you're going to feed the Machine for Data classification and tagging is the category of what type of data is.
 hope it helps.

Comment: Does tagging just help the programmer or also change the program?

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/ it helps the programmer, i don't know what you mean by changing the program. it basically tells the machine that' if you encounter this kind of word on a sentence, count it as negative/positive.

Comment: Ok thank you, just for reference, when I said changing the program I meant changing the way the program functions.